# nested ng-repeat: calling a function after all the ng-repeats have been loaded

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to know if there is a way to do a function call after all the nested ng-repeats have been loaded?

```
<ul class="topLevel" ng-repeat='item in standardContent'>
      <li><input type='checkbox'><img class="inputImage" src="pictures/library.png"/><span>{{item.title}}</span>
        <ul class="middleLevel" ng-repeat='child in item.children'>
          <li><input type='checkbox'><img class="inputImage" src="pictures/library.png"/><span>{{child.title}}</span>
            <ul class="middleLevel" ng-repeat='gChild in child.children'>
              <li><input type='checkbox'><img class="inputImage" src='pictures/bigFolder.png'/><span>{{gChild.title}}</span>
                <ul class="middleLevel" ng-repeat='ggChild in gChild.children'>
                  <li populate-src><input type='checkbox'><img  class="inputImage"/><span>{{ggChild.title}}</span>
                    <ul class="middleLevel" ng-repeat='gggChild in ggChild.children'>
                      <li populate-src ><input type='checkbox'><img  class="inputImage"/><span>{{gggChild.title}}</span></li>...
```

The array of object to be fed into the standardContent of the ul.topLevel has varied depth, and the img in each li has different image depending on its depth in the list. I have tried to create a directive and push all of the elements into a stack in order to determine the depth of the specific element. But I am not able to find a way to call a function after all the ng-repeats have been loaded to call the function to check the stack. Is there any way that I could do that?

Comment: You do not mention why you need to call the function after the `ng-repeat` has loaded. Maybe there is a better way to achieve your requirements.

Comment: i would like to make the src of the img tag to be dynamic. For example, at the last level of the list, I would like the image to be image "A", while the 2nd last level to be image "B" and the rest to be image "C".

Answer (score 0):

That looks pretty badass :)

Try to watch the `$last` value in the last ng-repeat. If its true you know that reached the end.

Actually I'm not sure, you might need to watch all repeats. If it so write your own ng-repeat which yields at every `$last === true` and watch/count the yields.